Error: PDDL Planning Service returned code 400 BAD REQUEST
Its my first time trying to use PDDL in Visual Studio Core. I was just following the tutorial with a demo project, trying to solve it. This is the answer I get when I do alt + P: Error: PDDL Planning Service returned code 400 BAD REQUEST
Im trying to use the default settings, https://solver.planning.domains/solve
Why do I get this error?
I was trying to solve the problem (it gets a solution in pddl.editor) but it doesnt compile in visual studio core

The online solver has been updated, and it looks like you're using an old endpoint. You should use the "Planning-as-a-Service" planner (add a new one in the plugin settings), and configure it like this:


Thank you so much, now at least im able to compile the hello world example, but mine its still giving the 400 error. Could you check my code? It compiles perfectly in pddl editor so i dont know if its a sintax error or what: https://editor.planning.domains/#read_session=H5luAA9QB3 (notice that when i import it to VS I make sure i ad :  (:requirements :strips  :typing :negative-preconditions :equality) so there are no errors

So if it's working on the online editor, then it must be a configuration problem with your vs code plugin. Want to share what the config looks like?
